# Selecting and reading values from nested attribute nodes in XML

Tags: php, xml, xmlwriter

I have a PHP script which reads XML file and converts it into my XML format. The original XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <products>
    <product>
      <id>1</id>
      <stock>23</stock>
      ... 6 more nodes....
      <pictures>
        <pic1>linktopic1.jpg</pic1>
        <pic2>linktopic2.jpg</pic2>
      </pictures>
      <tax_percent>...</tax_percent>
      <price_dc>....</price_dc>
      ...... some more nodes....
      <attributes>
        <attribute name="Sample attribute" value="Sample value" />
        <attribute name="Sample attribute 2" value="Sample value 2"/>
        .... 10+ attributes for each product....
      </attributes>

    </product>
   </products>
 </root>
```

I'm using XMLwriter to read XML and write to a new XML. All pictures and attributes which are in separate nodes have to be together in 1 string. I managed to do this for pictures but it's not working for attributes.

```
foreach($xml->children() as $products) { 
  foreach($products->children() as $product) {
      $newXML->startElement("product");
      $newXML->writeElement("ID", $product->id);
      $newXML->writeElement("Stock", $product->stock);
      $pic=""; // string resets for each product node
      $atr=""; // Attribute string
         foreach($product->pictures as $child) { // pictures
           if ($child->pic1!="") { $pic=$pic.$child->pic1.","; } // If the picture subnode exists it appends the image to previous ones 
           if ($child->pic2!="") { $pic=$pic.$child->pic2.","; }
           if ($child->pic3!="") { $pic=$pic.$child->pic3.","; }
         }
         foreach($product->attributes as $child) { //attributes
           if ($child->attribute['name']=="Sample attribute") { $atr=$atr.$child->attribute['name'].':'.$child->attribute['value'].','; }
           if ($child->attribute['name']=="Sample attribute 2") { $atr=$atr.$child->attribute['name'].':'.$child->attribute['value'].','; }
         }
        ..... some more spaghetti code....
```

Like I said, the code for pictures is working but for some reason the code for attributes only writes the first attribute of a product in a string and skips all others.

Anyone knows why the  foreach loop skips all other attribute nodes? To me it looks like it has some kind of a problem because attribute nodes have the same node name, while pictures have dynamic names, idk..

Comment: done any basic debugging, like doing some non-conditional output inside your attributes loop? Check if the loop does see all the attribute nodes. If that's the case, then your if()'s are incorrect and not triggering properly.

Comment: What is your desired output? *read XML and write to a new XML*...Enter [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) (not one `foreach` needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider going one level deeper to iterate on the `<attribute>` tags:

```
foreach($product->attributes->attribute as $child) { //attributes
   if ($child['name']=="Sample attribute") { $atr=$atr.$child['name'].': '.$child['value'].','; }
   if ($child['name']=="Sample attribute 2") { $atr=$atr.$child['name'].': '.$child['value'].','; }
}
```

In fact, you do not even need the `if` statement:

```
foreach($product->attributes->attribute as $child) { //attributes
   $atr=$atr.$child['name'].': '.$child['value'].',';
}
```

---

Alternatively, since you require a transformation of source XML to a final XML, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed specifically to transform XML documents. PHP with extension enabled in .ini file (*extension=php_xsl.so* or *extension=php_xsl.dll*) maintains an XSLT 1.0 processor. Below XSLT concatenates child values of pictures and attributes (scalable to 10+ nodes):

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file to be loaded below in PHP)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="products">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="product"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="product">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="id|stock"/>
      <pictures>
        <xsl:for-each select="pictures">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(pic1, ', ', pic2)" />
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>           
        </xsl:for-each>
      </pictures>
      <attributes>
        <xsl:for-each select="attributes/attribute">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name, ': ', @value)" />
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>           
        </xsl:for-each>        
      </attributes>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**PHP** *(no for loops, no if statements, no local variables, no spaghetti code)*

```
// LOAD XML AND XSL SOURCES
$xml = simplexml_load_file('Input.xml');    
$xsl = simplexml_load_file('XSLTScript.xsl');

// CONFIGURE TRANSFORMER
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

echo $newXML;

// <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
// <products>
//   <product>
//     <id>1</id>
//     <stock>23</stock>
//     <pictures>linktopic1.jpg, linktopic2.jpg</pictures>
//     <attributes>Sample attribute: Sample value, Sample attribute 2: Sample value 2</attributes>
//   </product>
// </products>
```

Comment: Ah thank you for your answer, the second foreach loop worked. I never heard of XSLT but I'll definitely try it out.